# Style vector tile layers point features in OpenLayers 3 get cropped

Tags: openlayers-3

Is there a way to avoid [cropped point styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxskH.png) when rendering in `ol.layer.VectorTile` Layer using OpenLayers 3 (v3.18.2)?

Here is the relevant code of the example:

```
layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
        url: 'http://localhost:8181/schools/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf',
        format: new ol.format.MVT(),
        tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 22}),
        tilePixelRatio: 16
    }),
    style: function(feature) {
        return new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(105, 105, 105, 1.0)'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    width: 1,
                    color: 'rgba(105, 105, 105, 0.3)'
                }),
                radius: 7
            }),
            text: new ol.style.Text({
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                fontFamily: 'Calibri,sans-serif',
                fontSize: 12,
                text: feature.get("count").toString(),
                labelYOffset: -12
            })
        });
    }
});
map.addLayer(layer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to generate your vector tiles differently, i.e. with a buffer, so your tiles also include nearby points from neighbouring tiles.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!!!! It worked!!! I've proposed the addition of that parameter in TileStache. https://github.com/TileStache/TileStache/pull/264/commits/cbacf9c7fdb17ac8d4e94631e0f6b9254888500d